# Get a full list of TCP ports that exist on a particular (windows/mac) device?

Tags: powershell, networking, tcp, terminal, netstat

I know the `netstat` command on both windows (powershell) and mac/linux will return information about the ports ***in use***

Is there some command (or option) to retrieve a **full list** of all TCP ports that exist on a device, irrespective of whether or not they're in use?

Note: I see [an excellent list of IANA assigned port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), which goes up to ~65000. But I can't see a specific max, and I'm not sure if all laptops/servers/VMs have that many ports.

Apologies in advance for my lack of knowledge around how ports work; they're something I rarely have need deal with directly.

Comment: 65535 is the max, and which "device" exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @l'L'l good question. I'm writing a simple function that simply gives the user a port that is not in use. I have used (some of) the IANA unassigned ranges. My main concern (and reason for this question) is that, depending on the device being used by whoever runs the function, the function may allocate them a port that doesn't exist on their device! The short answer is any laptop (running windows/macOS/linux), but possibly also VMS (through aws/gcp/azure). Sorry, not a simple answer.

Comment: Most devices if they are capable of TCP protocol would cover the entire range. If you are looking to assign ports then consider using the range `49,152` through `65,535`, since they are considered dynamic or "private"; `0-49151` are considered "registered" so that's where you could end up mistakenly assigning something that might eventually get used by a particular piece of hardware or software.

Comment: Simply ask TCP or UDP for the next one.

Comment: @RonMaupin is there a simple command for that?

Comment: Asking for Port 0 does that. It assigns one of the emphemeral ports.

Comment: @l'L'l please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341694/why-does-a-particular-user-profile-trigger-deceptive-site-ahead-message)

Comment: @user5783745: Interesting, thanks for the heads up :)